# iframe to load video works fine locally but not working in server

Tags: jquery, iframe, html5-video, resizable

I have a resizable iframe which load a local video.
When I was opening it direct from local file, the video loads perfectly and the resiza function works fine.

However, when I open the html using the local server, the video in the iframe dont load but it download automatically in the browser. Why does it happened?

```
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content"><img class="arrow" src="Capture.png"><iframe height="235px" width="290px" class="iframe" src="The Best Glasses For Your Face Shape (1).mp4"></iframe></div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `<video>` tag, to actually embed the file, rather than link to it:
instead of `<iframe>`, use `<iframe><video>`.

Comment: After ur advise I change it into this : <iframe class="iframe"><video width="235px" height="290px"><source src="The Best Glasses For Your Face Shape (1).mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></iframe> but the video dont show up

Comment: 1. Put it in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and 2. `height="290px"><source` is incorrect, source is an attribute, not a tag.

Comment: `<iframe class="iframe"><video width="235px" height="290px" src="The Best Glasses For Your Face Shape (1).mp4" type="video/mp4" /></iframe>` works.

Comment: It appears to be an issue with the iframe, which is preventing the playback of the video.